# Como colocar un label al lado de un div

Tags: html5

Tengo el siguiente código y no encuentro la forma de poder poner el `label` "Rango" a la izquierda del `div`

Alguna ayuda?

```html
<label for="reportrange">Rango:&nbsp;</label>
<div id="reportrange" style="margin-left: 110px;  background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 200px">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
  <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Podemos ayudarte pero ¿qué has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo lo que estas intentando pero bueno acá te dejo lo que haría yo para que queden uno al lado del otro.

```css
.flexbox-container {
        width: 300px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
    <label for="reportrange">Rango:&nbsp;</label> 
    <div id="reportrange" style=" background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 200px">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
        <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Creo que una explicación no caería mal, por ejemplo decirle al OP por que usas flexbox